# opencv and android background Substration error

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.10 and backgroundSubstrationMOG();
When I change it to opencv 3.0 it shows me error i check it there are only MOG2 and kNN background Substration when i use them its show error also

```
package org.opencv.samples.tutorial1;

import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.video.BackgroundSubtractorKNN;
import org.opencv.video.Video;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Tutorial1Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private boolean              mIsJavaCamera = true;
    private MenuItem             mItemSwitchCamera = null;

    private BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 sub;
    private Mat mGray;
    private Mat mRgb;
    private Mat mFGMask;
    private List<MatOfPoint> contours;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

public Tutorial1Activity() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
     sub = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    contours.clear();

    mGray = inputFrame.gray(); 

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mGray, mRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB); 


    sub.apply(mRgb, mFGMask, 0.1); 




    Imgproc.findContours(mFGMask, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL , Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    Imgproc.drawContours(mRgb, contours, -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

    return mRgb;

}
}
```

It is showing me this error

```
The constructor BackgroundSubtractorMOG2() is 
 undefined
- The constructor BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(long) is not 
 visible
```

It works on openCv 2.4.10

also I try this

```
sub =   Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

replace it with

```
 sub = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

when i use  sub =   Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

the error gone but when i run it on my phone its give stopped
but with   `sub = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();`
its give me error 
its

```
    The constructor BackgroundSubtractorMOG2() is 
     undefined
    - The constructor BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(long) is not 
     visible
_______________
```

---

the adb log here when i use

```
sub =   Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();



 07-19 01:50:38.727: I/OCVSample::Activity(9425): Instantiated new class org.opencv.samples.tutorial1.Tutorial1Activity
07-19 01:50:38.737: I/OCVSample::Activity(9425): called onCreate
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/CameraBridge(9425): Attr count: 6
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): Trying to get library list
07-19 01:50:38.757: E/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): Library list: ""
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): First attempt to load libs
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): Trying to init OpenCV libs
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): Trying to load library opencv_java3
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): Cannot load library "opencv_java3"
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java3 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial1-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.tutorial1-1]: findLibrary returned null
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:64)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:95)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:39)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:72)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at org.opencv.samples.tutorial1.Tutorial1Activity.onResume(Tutorial1Activity.java:90)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1202)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5404)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-19 01:50:38.757: W/System.err(9425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(9425): First attempt to load libs fails
07-19 01:50:38.757: D/OCVSample::Activity(9425): Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization
07-19 01:50:38.807: D/CameraBridge(9425): call surfaceChanged event
07-19 01:50:38.807: D/CameraBridge(9425): call checkCurrentState
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Service connection created
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Trying to get library path
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Trying to get library list
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Library list: "libopencv_java3.so"
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): First attempt to load libs
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Trying to init OpenCV libs
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Trying to load libs by dependency list
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Trying to load library /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java3.so
07-19 01:50:38.817: D/dalvikvm(9425): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java3.so 0x418d5ad8
07-19 01:50:38.847: D/dalvikvm(9425): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java3.so 0x418d5ad8
07-19 01:50:38.847: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): OpenCV libs init was ok!
07-19 01:50:38.847: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): First attempt to load libs is OK
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   videoio: Removing WinRT API headers by default
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Version control:               3.0.0-6-gc1f114b
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Platform:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Host:                        Darwin 13.2.0 i386
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Target:                      Linux 1 armv7-a
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     CMake generator:             Ninja
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Configuration:               Release
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   C/C++:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ (ver 4.8)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -fpic -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -fpic -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C Compiler:                  /usr/local/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -fpic -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -fvisibility=hidden -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -fpic -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -fvisibility=hidden -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Precompiled headers:         NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Extra dependencies:          z dl m log
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     3rdparty dependencies:       libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf tbb
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   OpenCV modules:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     To be built:                 hal core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d java stitching videostab
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Disabled:                    world
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Disabled by dependency:      -
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 viz
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Android: 
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Android ABI:                 armeabi-v7a with NEON
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     STL type:                    gnustl_static
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Native API level:            android-8
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     SDK target:                  android-14
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Android NDK:                 /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e (toolchain: arm-linux-androideabi-4.8)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     android tool:                /opt/android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android (Android SDK Tools, revision 24.1.2.)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Google Play manager:         NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Android examples:            YES
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   GUI: 
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     GTK+:                        NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     GThread :                    NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     GtkGlExt:                    NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     OpenGL support:              NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     VTK support:                 NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Media I/O: 
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     ZLib:                        z (ver 1.2.3)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     GDAL:                        NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Video I/O:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Other third-party libraries:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use IPP:                     NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use Eigen:                   NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.1 interface 6102)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use OpenMP:                  NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use GCD                      NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use Concurrency              NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use C=:                      NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use pthreads for parallel for:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):                                  NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use Cuda:                    NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Use OpenCL:                  NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Python 2:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.5)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Python 3:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Interpreter:                 NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Java:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     ant:                         /usr/local/bin/ant (ver 1.9.4)
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Java wrappers:               YES
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Java tests:                  YES
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Matlab:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     mex:                         NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Documentation:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Doxygen:                     NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     PlantUML:                    NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Tests and samples:
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Tests:                       YES
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     Performance tests:           NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):     C/C++ Examples:              NO
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   Install path:                  /builds/master_pack-android/build/o4a/install
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425):   cvconfig.h is in:              /builds/master_pack-android/build/o4a
07-19 01:50:38.847: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): -----------------------------------------------------------------
07-19 01:50:38.847: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Init finished with status 0
07-19 01:50:38.847: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Unbind from service
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(9425): Calling using callback
07-19 01:50:38.857: I/OCVSample::Activity(9425): OpenCV loaded successfully
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/CameraBridge(9425): call checkCurrentState
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/CameraBridge(9425): call processExitState: 0
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/CameraBridge(9425): call processEnterState: 1
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/CameraBridge(9425): call onEnterStartedState
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Connecting to camera
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Initialize java camera
07-19 01:50:38.857: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Trying to open camera with old open()
07-19 01:50:39.097: D/JavaCameraView(9425): getSupportedPreviewSizes()
07-19 01:50:39.097: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Set preview size to 800x480
07-19 01:50:39.107: D/dalvikvm(9425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 196K, 10% free 9183K/10196K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
07-19 01:50:39.107: I/dalvikvm-heap(9425): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.228MB for 1536016-byte allocation
07-19 01:50:39.137: D/dalvikvm(9425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 9% free 10683K/11700K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
07-19 01:50:39.137: D/JavaCameraView(9425): startPreview
07-19 01:50:39.187: E/dalvikvm(9425): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
07-19 01:50:39.187: D/dalvikvm(9425): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 9% free 10683K/11700K, paused 2ms+11ms, total 59ms
07-19 01:50:39.498: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Starting processing thread
07-19 01:50:39.498: I/Choreographer(9425): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-19 01:50:39.508: D/ION(9425): config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
07-19 01:50:39.508: D/MM_DEVICE(9425): Waiting for mm thread to come up
07-19 01:50:39.508: D/MM_DEVICE(9425): mm_device_thread starting
07-19 01:50:39.608: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 576000
07-19 01:50:39.608: W/dalvikvm(9425): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fb2930)
07-19 01:50:39.608: E/AndroidRuntime(9425): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9383
07-19 01:50:39.608: E/AndroidRuntime(9425): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 01:50:39.608: E/AndroidRuntime(9425):     at org.opencv.samples.tutorial1.Tutorial1Activity.onCameraFrame(Tutorial1Activity.java:114)
07-19 01:50:39.608: E/AndroidRuntime(9425):     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:393)
07-19 01:50:39.608: E/AndroidRuntime(9425):     at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:346)
07-19 01:50:39.608: E/AndroidRuntime(9425):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-19 01:50:39.658: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 576000
07-19 01:50:39.698: D/CameraBridge(9425): call checkCurrentState
07-19 01:50:39.698: D/CameraBridge(9425): call processExitState: 1
07-19 01:50:39.698: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Disconnecting from camera
07-19 01:50:39.698: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Notify thread
07-19 01:50:39.698: D/JavaCameraView(9425): Wating for thread
```